# Scan session items

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I tried to scan the items put in the session of my Spring MVC Project

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(HttpServletRequest request){
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    Enumeration<String> list=session.getAttributeNames();
    while(list.hasMoreElements())
        System.out.println(list.nextElement());
    return "index";     
}//welcome
```

I have in output:

```
scopedTarget.carrello
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.scopedTarget.carrello
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.scopedTarget.cliente
scopedTarget.cliente
num_articoli
totale_carrello
```

carrello and utente are two beans with scope=session ; instead num_articoli and totale_carrello are two attributes written with @SessionAttributes.

My questions are:

1. What does that mean "org.springframework.web.context.request...." and the scopedtarget prefix?
2. Why I can access, in the jsp page,only at the SessionAttributes?How can I access to the parameters of beans with scope=session?

Thanks

Comment: A `session` scoped bean is to be used between beans with dependency injection not for use to display values in a web page for this simply use session attributes (`session.setAttribute`). The other 2 beans are related to session scoped beans and are the destruction callbacks to cleanup resources when a session is ended.

Comment: But  instead ,I can see the attributes written with @SessionAttributes  inside a jsp page .Why?So, if i want to display the user's information inside of a jsp page, what's the best solution?Is it a good idea to declare the user bean with scope= session?

Comment: No it isn't the best way, as I tried to convey in my comment. Session scoped beans have a different purpose. You are better of adding it yourself to the session. As stated although they are scoped to the session a `session` scoped bean is for different purposes.